# Resilience4j.retry with exception is not working

Tags: java, rest, circuit-breaker, retry-logic, resilience4j

I am using [resilience4j.retry](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry) with [resilience4j.circuitbreaker](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker). `Service1` is calling another service `Service2`, which can throw exceptions. Even if I get exceptions, I should try to connect for at least defined no of times `waitDuration * maxRetryAttempts`.

> Service1 --->    calling   ---> Service2

**application.yml**

```
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    service1:
      maxRetryAttempts: 4
      waitDuration: 1000 #ms
      retryExceptions:  
        - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
        - org.apache.thrift.TException
        - java.net.ConnectException
```

**Service1Repository.java**

```
Service2Response response = CircuitBreaker.decorateSupplier(circuitBreaker,
                                    Retry.decorateSupplier(retry, () -> {
                                        try {
                                            return service2.getdata(params);
                                        } catch (TException e) {
                                            log.error("msg", e);
                                            throw new Service1Exception("msg", e);
                                        }
                                    })
                            ).get();
```

However, when `Service2` is down, it is not retrying (max 4 times, each after 1000ms should happen) I am getting a response (`null` in my case) immediately. I tried with increasing values (10000ms), still the same. I am seeing logs are printed but service should wait for `waitDuration * maxRetryAttempts` if `Serviece2` is down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch checked exceptions, you have to use `decorateCallable`.

Comment: Do you know the reason why the decorateRunnable only catches RuntimeException and Exception?

Comment: Because you usually shouldn't catch Throwable/Error.